# How to create nested elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this array of strings `var arr = ["ul", "li", "strong", "em", "u"]`.

How can I make these into DOM Elements one inside another from left to right, first element as the root element. Without using ID because of some reason.

And maybe by using loop for it to be flexible to any number of elements.

`var new_element = document.createElement(arr[0]);`

I'm expecting something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong><em><u>Text Here</u></em></strong></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to know about [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) which avoids needing to query the result to get the deepest value because it starts with the deepest element and works out. The return value will be the topmost element:

```js
var arr = ["ul", "li", "strong", "em", "u"]

let el = arr.reduceRight((el, n) => {
  let d = document.createElement(n)
  d.appendChild(el)
  return d
}, document.createTextNode("Text Here"))

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el)
```

```html
<div id = "container"></div>
```

It also fails gracefully with an empty array:

```js
var arr = []

let el = arr.reduceRight((el, n) => {
  let d = document.createElement(n)
  d.appendChild(el)
  return d
}, document.createTextNode("Text Here"))

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el)
```

```html
<div id = "container"></div>
```

Comment: Great! Works as expected. I'll be analyzing how this works and read about the reduce and reduceRight function. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Node.prototype.appendChild`.

https://jsbin.com/hizetekato/edit?html,js,output

```js
var arr = ["ul", "li", "strong", "em", "u"];

function createChildren(mount, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((parent, elementName, i) => {
    const element = document.createElement(elementName);
    parent.appendChild(element);
    return element;
  }, mount);
}

const deepest = createChildren(document.querySelector('#root'), arr);

deepest.innerText = 'WebDevNSK'
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Seems like this is what I am looking for. I'll try to analyze it. And read about .reduce() Thank you btw.

Comment: What about `=> parent.appendChild(document.createElement(elementName));`? [`Node.appendChild` returns the appended child.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) However, readability is probably more important that concision.

Answer (score 0):

[`createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) and run the array through a loop. On each iteration [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
const useless = ["ul", "li", "strong", "em", "u"];

let previous;
for (let u = 0; u < useless.length; u++) {
  const current = document.createElement(useless[u]);
  if (u === 0) {
    frag.appendChild(current);
  } else {
    previous.appendChild(current);
  }
  previous = current;
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
ul {
  outline: 5px dashed green;
  padding: 15px;
}

li {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 12px;
}

strong {
  outline: 5px dashed red;
  padding: 9px
}

em {
  outline: 5px dashed grey;
  padding: 6px
}

u {
  outline: 5px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

u::before {
  content: 'THIS TEXT SHOULD BE UNDERLINED'
}
```